# DS160 vs Appointment Interview Location

Tags: visas, uk-citizens

I submitted my DS160 for a non-immigrant visa and selected Belfast as the location as I believed that to be the most suitable at the time. When it came to the appointment schedule, I chose London as it was a better date. My interview is tomorrow and I have just realised this discrepency.

Should I create a new DS160 form? Will this scupper my chances of getting the Visa?

Thanks

Comment: did you end up running into any issues with your interview? I've made the same mistake, and want to make sure that I don't need to fill out a new DS-160 with the correct location.

Comment: No issues - see the answer below.

Answer (score 11):

Panic over, should have looked closer.

From US VISA Site : https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/forms/ds-160--online-nonimmigrant-visa-application/frequently-asked-questions.html

**What happens to my DS-160 if I select a U.S. Embassy or Consulate where I will be applying for my visa, but end up making an interview appointment instead at another U.S. Embassy or Consulate?**

The Embassy or Consulate at which you actually apply should be able to access your form using the barcode on your DS-160 confirmation page, which you must bring to the visa interview. For example, a business traveler intends to apply for his visa at the U.S. Embassy in City X, so he selects City X as the location where he will submit his application when he completes his DS-160. He then has an urgent reason to travel to City Y on business. Because there is a U.S. Consulate in City Y, he schedules an appointment for a visa interview there, using the barcode from his completed DS-160 application for appointment scheduling. The U.S. Consulate in City Y is able to accept his DS-160 even though it lists the U.S. Embassy in City X as the location where he originally intended to submit his application.

Answer (score 1):

Right, so also had this problem. Called up and the advisor on the phone told me to do another one.  And I found the following information which is confusing because it appears to contradict the "city x, city y" information given above: https://photos.state.gov/libraries/unitedkingdom/164203/pdf/Belfast-FAQs-2015.pdf

I am none the wiser and spending an evening doing another one :-/

Comment: Update on this, I called the helpline again and they still told me I need to do a new DS-160, but this involves rescheduling the appointment!  At this stage, I'm better off just trying in Belfast, and if I have to do another one, getting a new appointment after that.  I was then told to do whatever the state.gov FAQ told me to do.  It looks like the travel.state.gov FAQ says I will be OK.  I've printed out the FAQ to take to the interview to show  (https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/forms/ds-160-online-nonimmigrant-visa-application/ds-160-faqs.html)